# Do Omnet++ and Inet 4 and above support multi-radio interfaces for wireless nodes

Tags: omnet++

Do Omnet++ and Inet 4 and above support multi-radio interfaces for wireless nodes such as Adhoc nodes? One of its applications, simulating wireless nodes for estimating self-interference. Another application is simulating multi-channel wireless networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, as the following [tutorial shows](https://inet.omnetpp.org/docs/showcases/wireless/multiradio/doc/index.html)

(BTW, multiple wireless interfaces are also supported in INET 3.x)

Comment: I has read the link before, I want to simulate the problem without access point and allocate various channels to the multi radio wireless node. What are differences between wireless interface and gate?